# Add Column to sale order lines from product.template in Odoo 15

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-15

Products in odoo have informations like name,type,price,Internal Reference ect..
[image]
I want to add Internal Reference of a product in sale order lines
[image: Sale Order Lines]

as you see in the picture we have in order lines product,description,qty,price ect..
i want to add Internal Reference to this infos.

how can i add Internal Reference from image 1 (product) to image 2 (Order lines)

Comment: Where do you want to add the information? As new column (new field in `sale.order.line`)? Or as info in column "Description"?

Comment: as field in sale.order.line

Comment: Then create a char field with `related` like `related="product_id.default_code"`

Comment: in sale_order_line.py ?

Comment: i did what u told me in sale_order_line.py and i get this error
Field "default_code" does not exist in model "sale.order.line"
this is what i added 
    default_code = fields.Many2one(related='product_id.default_code')

Comment: Why `Many2one`?

Comment: im new to this 
okay i dont need many2one

Comment: what should i write to get the reference

Comment: still `default_code` or as i already wrote `related="product_id.default_code"`

Comment: i did it and it works

Comment: what if i want to get the suppliers of the product

Comment: is it the same way as internal ref

Comment: Should work the same way.

Comment: can you please take a look this problem its similar to this one

Comment: here is the link 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75118734/add-quantity-on-hand-and-the-suppliers-of-product-to-sale-order-lines-from-produ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inherit sale.order.line and add a field

```
default_code = fields.Char(string='Internal Reference ', related="product_id.default_code")
```

add this `default_code` field in xml by inheriting the the `order_lines`
view.

Comment: can you please take a look at this problem its similar to this one 
i need just a little help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75118734/add-quantity-on-hand-and-the-suppliers-of-product-to-sale-order-lines-from-produ

Comment: Okay... I will.but if this is the right answer for you then you can mark this answer as correct answer for this question, so that other might get help from this as well