# Add quantity on hand and the suppliers of product to sale order lines from product.template in Odoo 15

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-15

Products in odoo have informations like name,type,price,Internal Reference ect..

[image]

here I want to add quantity on hand and the suppliers of a product in sale order lines Sale Order Lines
[image]
as you see in the picture we have in order lines product,description,qty,price ect.. i want to add quantity on hand and the suppliers to this infos.

how can i add quantity on hand  from image 1 (product) to image 2 (Order lines), and the suppliers too

i tried this code

```
qty_on_hand = fields.Char(related="product_id.qty_available")
```

but i got this error

> odoo type of related field sale.order.line.qty_on_hand is inconsistent with product.product.qty_available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what is `suppliers` explain that please. i mean what will that field contain..
and for the `quantity available` you are doing it a bit wrong.
see the code below... you have to do like this...

inherit sale.order.line and add a field

```
qty_on_hand = fields.Float('On Hand Qty', related='product_id.qty_available')
```

add this qty_available field in xml by inheriting the the order_lines view thats all for `on hand quantity`.

Comment: yes the qty_on_hand code is working

Comment: and i want to display all the names of the suppliers related to product in sale order line

Comment: first you have to create a `many2many` field like `tax_ids` in `sale_order_line`,

In python inherit the `sale.order.line` and use search for the `product_id`  in `product.product` you will get the product record, there is a one2many field for the `vendors` which is `seller_ids` in products master, fetch `vendors` by using `for loop` and then store it in that `many2many` field which you created in sale.order.line the `vendor_id`

Comment: i understand but i dont know how to write the code down
can u write it please